# Predicate that turns an expression into right bracketed form?

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write a predicate `rightBrack(E1, E2)` where `E2` is the expression `E1` but in right bracketed form. An expression is defined as:

```
 Expr ::= lit(i)
         |add(Expr, Expr)
         |sub(Expr, Expr)
```

So for example if `E1 = add(add(add(lit(2), lit(3)), lit(4)),lit(5))` then `E2` should be `add(lit(2), add(lit(3), add(lit(4), lit(5))))`

I am not comfortable with Prolog at all, and I do not have much experience with it. With that said, I tried writing the following which does not work and I don't know how to make it work. Any help is appreciated.

```
rightBrack(add(add(E1, E2), E3), add(E4, add(E5, E6))) :-
   rightBrack(E1, E4),
   rightBrack(E2, E5),
   rightBrack(E3, E6).
rightBrack(add(E1, E2), add(E3, E4)) :-
   rightBrack(E1, E3),
   rightBrack(E2, E4).
rightBrack(sub(E1, E2), sub(E3, E4)) :-
   rightBrack(E1, E3),
   rightBrack(E2, E4).
rightBrack(lit(N), lit(N)).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
noadd(lit(_)).
noadd(sub(_,_)).

rightBrack(add(add(E1, E2), E3), E4) :-
   rightBrack(add(E1,add(E2,E3)), E4).
rightBrack(add(E1, E2), add(E3, E4)) :-
   noadd(E1),
   rightBrack(E1, E3),
   rightBrack(E2, E4).
rightBrack(sub(E1, E2), sub(E3, E4)) :-
   rightBrack(E1, E3),
   rightBrack(E2, E4).
rightBrack(lit(N), lit(N)).
```

But, ... how can we be sure about this? Maybe it is incorrect, too?

Answer (score 0):

Nice problem, the transformation need to change the tree from

```
?- draw(add(add(add(lit('2'), lit('3')), lit('4')),lit('5'))).

               add
                |
            +-------+
           add     lit
            |       |
        +------+    |
       add    lit   |
        |      |    |
     +----+    |    |
    lit  lit   |    |
     |    |    |    |
     |    |    |    |
     2    3    4    5
```

to

```
?- draw(add(lit('2'), add(lit('3'), add(lit('4'), lit('5'))))).

            add
             |
     +---------+
    lit       add
     |         |
     |    +-------+
     |   lit     add
     |    |       |
     |    |    +----+
     |    |   lit  lit
     |    |    |    |
     |    |    |    |
     2    3    4    5
```

I've renamed some constant (just easier to read, to me)

```
l2r(+(A,B),+(C,D)) :-
    l2r(A,B, C,D), !.
l2r(A, A).

l2r(+(A1,A2),B1, A3,+(A4,B2)) :-
    l2r(A1,B1, A3,B2),
    l2r(A2,A4).
l2r(A1,+(B1,B2), A2,+(B3,B4)) :- % as noted by @false
    l2r(B1,B2, B3,B4),
    l2r(A1,A2).
l2r(A,B, A,B).
```

mini test:

```
?- l2r(+(+(+(1,2),3),4),R),display(R).
+(1,+(3,+(2,4)))
R = 1+ (3+ (2+4)).

?- l2r(+(1,+(+(2,3),4)),R),display(R).
+(1,+(2,+(3,4)))
R = 1+ (2+ (3+4)).
```

Comment: @false: I know, I wanted just hint about the tree transformation, so I skipped over the exact symbols set. I renamed on purpose...